# CMDIFrameWnd::MDIGetActive returns null when called from external code

Tags: c++, mfc, com, mdi

I have inherited some legacy code that i'm required to integrate with a modern c# GUI. The codebase is a MFC MDI application, that creates a type library and registers a COM component to expose the application API for external applications and scripting.

Throughout the MFC application (henceforth I will refer to the MFC code as "the application") there is a function that checks for an active MDI document and returns it, or null. This method is called from a "MainFrame" class which inherits CMDIFrameWnd. it looks something like this:

```
CMDIChildWnd * pChildFrame = MDIGetActive();
if (pChildFrame)
{
    CDocument *pDoc = (CDocument *) pChildFrame->GetActiveDocument();
    if (pDoc)
    {
        return(pDoc);
    } else { 
        return NULL; 
}
```

I have created a test c# console application and can successfully import the COM component and access the API, and make calls to it. The problem is that whenever I call something that requires an active document via the API, MDIGetActive() returns null. For example, I can open a document via the API, and I can visually confirm it opens in the running MFC application. But if I call the API method to save this file, the active document is null. But if I call the same method via the application GUI, this works fine. It is the same function call, the exposed API method is just a wrapper.

Strangely enough when I open a file via the API method, it eventually executes the same check for an active document which succeeds. After getting the active document, it calls CDocument::UpdateAllViews() to update the UI. Any calls made after this via the API will result in no active document.

I'm at a loss here, I can't understand why the active document is null. I'm still working my way through MFC documentation but I haven't found anything that would suggest why this is the case. Does anyone know?

Comment: Pay attention to `MDIGetActive();` and `pChildFrame->GetActiveDocument();` ... are those objects active when you call them ?

Comment: @flaviu2 it may not have been clear in my post but MDIGetActive() is the call that fails, the call for GetActiveDocument() is never reached when using the API. The method is called from the "MainFrame" class which inherits CMDIFrameWnd. I have assumed the mainframe is active, but is there a way to be sure?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to avoid any `GetActiveWhatever()` method is the following code, which can be called from your `CYourApp` class:

```
POSITION posDoc, pos = GetFirstDocTemplatePosition();
while (NULL != pos)
{
    CDocTemplate* pDocTemplate = (CDocTemplate*)GetNextDocTemplate(pos);
    posDoc = pDocTemplate->GetFirstDocPosition();
    while(NULL != posDoc)
    {
        CDocument* pDoc = pDocTemplate->GetNextDoc(posDoc);
        if(NULL != pDoc)
            pDoc->UpdateAllViews(pSender, lHint, pHint);
    }
}
```

Of course, once you have the document, you'll have any view attached from that document.